# Sylow subgroups of a group $\mathbb{Z}/18\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

How can we determine Sylow subgroups of a group $\mathbb{Z}/18\mathbb{Z}$? I know that we have one $9$-Sylow subgroup and nine $2$-Sylow subgroups but I have no idea how to write them all down.

Comment: Isn't $\mathbb Z/18\mathbb Z$ abelian? And so all its Sylow subroups are unique?

Comment: Are you sure there are 9 2-Sylow subgroups. I think there is just one.

Comment: 1 9-subgroup + 9 2-sylow subgroups gives you more than 18 elements.

Comment: How? We have 8 nontrivial elements in 9-subgroup and 1 nontrivial element in each 2-subgroup so we have 8+9+unit=18.

Comment: Applying Sylow's Theorem 3 you get 1 for 2 sylow right?

Comment: Some elements aren't contained in any Sylow subgroup.

Comment: For example, $3$ is such an element because it has order 6. This is not a prime power. For that matter, $1$ also is not in any Sylow subgroup.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Under the canonical projection, the subgroups of $\mathbb Z/18\mathbb Z$ correspond to the divisors of $18$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Keep in mind that 0 has to be present in all the subgroups.